# Is there an elegant way to return the second found element of std::adjacent_find?

Tags: c++, algorithm

If you want to return the second element of `adjacent_find`, instead of the first, is there a nice way to solve this without handling the special case that no element is found?

So I would like equivalent code of the following function (such that it is not necessary to write your own function for that):

```
template<class Range, class Pred>
auto adjacent_find_second(Range&& range, Pred pred)
{
    auto it = std::ranges::adjacent_find(range, pred);
    if(it == range.end()) { return it; }
    else return ++it;
}
```

The problem is that the iterators that `std::adjacent_find` can possibly return are not consecutive.
It can return all possible iterators of the range (including `end`), but not an iterator to the last element.

A reimplementatiton of `adjacent_find` would be more efficient because it could just return the iterator to the second element in the found pair. This also would not need to do that additional check.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem without the check?

Comment: I can personally promise you that that one `==` check is not the bottleneck in your program. I say that without looking at your code at all, because I'm pretty confident about that. You've written a very good function to get a job done, I suggest you go with it. Micro-optimizing every `if` statement and every cheap comparison is not productive.

Comment: Why do you have an issue with that `if` check?

Comment: It is not so much about performance aspect of the additonal check, but about the about the added complexity. Either you do not have an extra function (then it is not very expressive. Or you have to write your own standard-function and always include it when you need it.

Comment: May I ask why you specifically need the second one to be returned?

Comment: I want to find an element with a property such that the predecessor also fulfills some property.

Comment: Would it suffice to use `adjacent_find` on a reversed view of the original range?

Comment: Ok, but that element, either doesn't exists (the valued returned by `adjacent_find` is equal to `end`) or it's the next. Instead of writing a function the result of which should be tested again, you could just add a bit of logic (`++it`) in the happy path of the caller of `adjacent_find`.

Comment: `it += (it != range.end());` `return it;` There, no `if` statement, no special case, it always adds something (it's just `0` when the element wasn't found). :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger please note that you're implicitly requiring random-access iterators :-)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Look, being clever for the sake of cleverness (the version of cleverness with the most negative connotations) sometimes requires sacrifice. ;-)